# Fragments in Android- Cant dynamically edit text view

Tags: android, fragment

I get an error when I try and use:
TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
inside my FragmentOne class.

I'm new to fragments and im hoping to learn PagerView but i cant work out how to dynamically change my widgets.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    FragmentOne mFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            mFrag = new FragmentOne();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_layout, mFrag).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout">

   <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Yellow World!");
        return v;
    }
}
```

**layout/fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blellow World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Log File: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Projects?select=log.txt
The error is "Unable to start activity"
The error goes away if i remove the

```
tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText("Yellow World!");
```

lines from the FragmentOne class.

I've only learnt fragments today so im sorry if its something simple!

Comment: If it helps ive been following this tutorial http://danielnadeau.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/introduction-to-using-fragments-in.html

Comment: Why you use getView()?? Just change it to tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1); and try again

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. The getView() was from another Question that i found on a similar topic

Comment: I will make my comment an answer so that you can accept it for others to see it if they have same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the inflated view instead of getView().

```
 tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```